# How is passing a generator to Depends make the generator act like a contextmanager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I was going through a tutorial on fast api and I came across something like below

```
def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        print("from finally block")
        db.close()
```

```
@app.get("/")
async def read_all(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    res = db.query(models.Todos).all()
    print("from endpoint")
    return res
```

result

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:39088 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
from endpoint
INFO:     127.0.0.1:39088 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
from finally block
```

why does Depends(get_db) seem to act like somekind of contextmanager?.
the `"from finally block"` print statement does not get executed until the end of the `read_all` method

doing something like

```
class SomeDependency:
    def __enter__(self):
        print("entering")
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("exited")

def hello():
    try:
        yield SomeDependency()
    finally:
        print("yolo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   next(hello())
```

the `finally` block gets executed immediately after the call to `next`.

what why does the `finally` block of the `get_db` not execute immediately when passed to `Depends`?

Comment: Dependencies in FastAPI is cached across the whole request (if you're using `get_db` in multiple places in the dependency hierarchy, it does only get resolved once; thus, I'm guessing it also only gets collected after the dependency cache gets removed. You're not looking at a direct function call as in your own example, the actual call happens far further down the stack.

Comment: @MatsLindh what I do not understand. even if the function call happens further down.
the second `hello` yields it value, it immediately calls the `finally block`. but not when fastapi makes the `get_db ` yield its value. its acting like a context manager. how is it able to get you the actual value from your generator but not make it exit immediately?

Comment: @MatsLindh, FYI, it's done explicitly via the ```with``` statement. See [the implementation](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.89.1/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py#L15) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to clearly understand the concept of the context manager and the generator. Basically they are totally unrelated different concepts. I'll briefly explain them.

The context manager is a part of the `with` statement feature, which is a syntax sugar for boiler plate code of `try/finally` block ensuring to finalize things. See [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) for detail. In your second example, no context manager is involved because there's no `with` statement.

And the generator is a syntax sugar for boiler plate code of defining an iterator.(But it's a quite complex feature called [coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) from the implementation point of view.) See [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) for detail. In your second example, the `finally` clause will be executed when an iterator returned by the `hello()` is finalized(when the reference count reaches zero).

Although I said the two are totally unrelated before, there exists a little relation actually - a syntax sugar for boiler plate code of defining a context manager class, defining a context manager via a generator, like the following.(It's scrapped from [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) and edited).

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def managed_resource(...):
    resource = acquire_resource(...)
    try:
        yield resource
    finally:
        release_resource(resource)

with managed_resource(...) as resource:
    ...
```

And returning the focus to the FastAPI `Depends`, if you give a generator as an argument, it will internally create a context manager using the above feature. You can see [the implementation](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.89.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L461).

Comment: I do understand how a context manager and generator works otherwise how was I able to infer that it s actually what FastAPI was doing?. I mean that should implicitly tell you I do know?smh. and also my bad. the example with `__enter__` was wrong i didn't use that as a context manager in that example

Anyway thank you for your explanation and links they are very helpful. It answers my question

Comment: You are right. I thought that because you mixed a context manager and a generator unsensibly. Anyway it's good to hear it was helpful.